# how to display date using javascript?

Tags: javascript

### as i try the below javascript code to display date

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> javascript</h1>
<button type="button" onclick=document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()">click me to display date and time.</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the quotes in onclick="..."

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> javascript</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()">click me to display date and time.</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

There were few corrections:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1> javascript</h1>
  <!-- added missing qoutes for onclick -->
  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML= new Date();">click me to display date and time.</button>
  <!-- added missing, new keyword for Date() -->
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code will be helpful...

```js
var date = new Date();
var n = date.toDateString();
var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();

alert(n + ' ' + time);
```

you can even put this in HTML DIV tag as per you need

JS

```
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = n + ' ' + time;
```

HTML

```
<div id='time'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick=document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()">click me to display
```

This needs to be fixed. When you wrote `onclick=` you don't have a `"` at the beginning.
Simple Fix, add it:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()">click me to display
```

Working Fix:
https://jsfiddle.net/4cjhg2uo/